# how to set value for asp Textbox inside jquery modal by row in gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem regarding textbox(tb) inside jquery modal, inside the gridview. Basically, the problem is that the value of the tb same as I click the modal from other row in gridview even I put "tr" to set the row. The key are 'id_rN' and 'rN'. The situation is:

1. Click modal link for row 1 in gridview
2. Insert data in tb in modal (eg: hello)
3. Close modal
4. Click modal link for row 2 in gridview and the value is same as row 1

I will show the picture of it:

[Click "Add/Edit" at 'Remarks' column to show modal pop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6GwW.png)

[Modal Textbox row1 show 'hello'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUGOr.png)

You can see that modal tb get same value both row1 and row2.

This is the script:

```
$('a[data-toggle=modal]').click(function () {

            var data_pN = String($(".pN", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
            var data_cN = String($(".cN", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
            var data_aN = String($(".aN", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
            var data_rN = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').find('[id*="id_rN"]', $(this).closest("tr")).val(); //variable for textbox in modal



            $('input[id*="id_pN"]').val(data_pN);
            $('input[id*="id_cN"]').val(data_cN);
            $('input[id*="id_aN"]').val(data_aN);
            $('[id*="rN"]', $(this).closest("tr")).val(data_rN); //get value from texbox modal to textbox for column 'Remarktest'

        });
```

This is the gridview html:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"
                CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" GridLines="None" RowStyle-BackColor="#5AC3DE"
                AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#1ac6ff" Font-Size="Smaller">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Project No." HeaderText="Project No." ItemStyle-CssClass="pN" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Ctr No." HeaderText="Ctr No." ItemStyle-CssClass="cN" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Activity" HeaderText="Activity" ItemStyle-CssClass="aN" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ad" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="rN" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="Remark" HeaderText="Remark" ItemStyle-CssClass="rN"  Visible="false"/>--%>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <!-- Link trigger modal -->
                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" id="modalLink">Add/Edit</a>
                            <%--<asp:TextBox ID="rN" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                            <!-- Modal tabindex="-1" role="dialog" div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document"-->
                            <div class="modal container fade" id="myModal" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="width: 60%;
                                margin-bottom: 20%">
                                <%--<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">--%>
                                <%--<div class="modal-content">--%>
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                                        Details</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <h4>
                                                    Project No.</h4>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="id_pN" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ReadOnly="true" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <h4>
                                                    Ctr No.</h4>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="id_cN" runat="server" CssClass=" form-control" ReadOnly="true" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <h4>
                                                    Activity</h4>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="id_aN" runat="server" CssClass=" form-control" ReadOnly="true" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <h4>
                                                    Remark</h4>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="id_rN" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4"
                                                    Font-Size="Small"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">

                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" >
                                            Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Actual" HeaderText="Actual To End of Week" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sat st">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_nt_sat" runat="server" CssClass="tb_day"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sat ot">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_ot_sat" runat="server" CssClass="tb_day" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sun st">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_nt_sun" runat="server" CssClass="tb_day" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sun ot">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_ot_sun" runat="server" CssClass="tb_day" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mon st">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_nt_mon" runat="server" CssClass="tb_day"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mon ot">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_ot_mon" runat="server" CssClass="tb_day" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tue st">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_nt_tue" runat="server" CssClass="tb_day"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tue ot">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_ot_tue" runat="server" CssClass="tb_day" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Wed st">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_nt_wed" runat="server" CssClass="tb_day"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Wed ot">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_ot_wed" runat="server" CssClass="tb_day" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Thu st">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_nt_thu" runat="server" CssClass="tb_day"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Thu ot">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_ot_thu" runat="server" CssClass="tb_day" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fri st">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_nt_fri" runat="server" CssClass="tb_day"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fri ot">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_ot_fri" runat="server" CssClass="tb_day" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="hourtest">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="hTest" runat="server" CssClass="tb_day" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Week" HeaderText="Weekly Total" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Remain" HeaderText="Remaining hour" />
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Glad anyone can help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

**HTML MARKUP:**
Add a class toyour textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="id_pN" runat="server" CssClass="cls_pN form-control" ReadOnly="true" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="id_cN" runat="server" CssClass="cls_cN form-control" ReadOnly="true" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:TextBox>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('a[data-toggle=modal]').click(function () {
            var self=$(this);
            var selfTR=self.closest('tr');

            // get current row textbox value
            var txt_p=selfTR.find(".cls_pN").val();
            var txt_c=selfTR.find(".cls_cN").val();

            alert(txt_p);
            alert(txt_c);
    });
```

Comment: I've done this part where to show pN, cN and aN in the modal. However, the problem is that I have to get data from "Remark" texbox and pass to textbox outside modal which is in "Remark Test" column.